# Union and intersection of two arrays

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting

> ## Problem:
>
> Write an algorithm, to find the union and intersection sorted in ascending order, between the elements of two arrays
>
> ## Input Format
>
> The first line contains an integer, n1 , denoting the size of the first array.
>
> The second line contains n1 space-separated integers representing elements of the first array.
>
> The third line contains an integer, n2 , denoting the size of the second array.
>
> The fourth line contains n2 space-separated integers representing elements of the second array.
>
> ## Constraints
>
> Apart from Array, no other data structure can be used
>       Output elements should be sorted in ascending order
>       Array should be sorted using Bubble Sort
>
> ## Output Format
>
> First line, union of space-separated elements of both array elements, sorted in ascending order
>
> Second line, intersection of space-separated elements of both arrays elements, sorted in ascending order

---

## Solution:

```
"""
   1) Sort two arrays
   2) Find union and intersecton of two sorted arrays
"""
def swap(array, indexI, indexJ):
    temp = array[indexI]
    array[indexI] = array[indexJ]
    array[indexJ] = temp

def bubbleSort(array):
    n = len(array)
    for indexI in range(n):
        exchanges = 0
        for indexJ in range(n-1, indexI, -1):
            if array[indexJ] < array[indexJ-1]:
                swap(array, indexJ, indexJ-1)
                exchanges += 1
        if exchanges == 0:
            break
def intersection(arrayOne, arrayTwo):
    arrayOneIndex = 0
    arrayTwoIndex =0
    sizeOfArrayOne = len(arrayOne)
    sizeOfArrayTwo = len(arrayTwo)
    array = []
    while arrayOneIndex < sizeOfArrayOne and arrayTwoIndex < sizeOfArrayTwo:
        if arrayOne[arrayOneIndex] < arrayTwo[arrayTwoIndex]:
            arrayOneIndex += 1
        elif arrayOne[arrayOneIndex] > arrayTwo[arrayTwoIndex]:
            arrayTwoIndex += 1
        else:
            array.append(arrayOne[arrayOneIndex])
            arrayOneIndex += 1
            arrayTwoIndex += 1
    return array

def union(arrayOne, arrayTwo):
    arrayOneIndex = 0
    arrayTwoIndex =0
    sizeOfArrayOne = len(arrayOne)
    sizeOfArrayTwo = len(arrayTwo)
    array = []
    while arrayOneIndex < sizeOfArrayOne and arrayTwoIndex < sizeOfArrayTwo:
        if arrayOne[arrayOneIndex] < arrayTwo[arrayTwoIndex]:
            array.append(arrayOne[arrayOneIndex])
            arrayOneIndex += 1
        elif arrayOne[arrayOneIndex] > arrayTwo[arrayTwoIndex]:
            array.append(arrayTwo[arrayTwoIndex])
            arrayTwoIndex += 1
        else:
            array.append(arrayOne[arrayOneIndex])
            arrayOneIndex += 1
            arrayTwoIndex += 1
    if arrayOneIndex == sizeOfArrayOne:
        while arrayTwoIndex < sizeOfArrayTwo:
            array.append(arrayTwo[arrayTwoIndex])
            arrayTwoIndex += 1
    else:
        while arrayOneIndex < sizeOfArrayOne:
            array.append(arrayOne[arrayOneIndex])
            arrayOneIndex += 1
    return array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sizeOne = int(input())
    try:
        arrayOne = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        sys.exit()
    sizeTwo = int(input())
    try:
        arrayTwo = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    except:
        print('Invalid syntax')
        sys.exit()
    bubbleSort(arrayOne)
    bubbleSort(arrayTwo)
    intersectionArray = intersection(arrayOne, arrayTwo)
    unionArray = union(arrayOne, arrayTwo)
    print(*unionArray, sep=" ")
    print(*intersectionArray, sep=" ")
```

---

## Correctness

```
Input 

3
4 5 7
5
6 9 5 7 1

Output

1 4 5 6 7 9
5 7

Input

6
1 1 8 9 0 5
4
0 7 3 4

Output

0 1 3 4 5 7 8 9
0
```

---

Question:

0) How to avoid such syntax? `while arrayOneIndex < sizeOfArrayOne and arrayTwoIndex < sizeOfArrayTwo`

1) Does the code require better error handling?

2) Can this code get more pythonic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Advice 1**

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has some (minor) complains: the names of functions and their arguments should be `funky_functions` instead of `funkyFunctions`, and `funky_argument` instead of `funkyArgument`.

**Advice 2**

In Python, you can say

```
def funky1():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

def funky2():
    arr = []
    for i in range(10):
        arr.append(i)
    return arr
```

So you may come up with:

```
def intersection(array_one, array_two):
    array_one_index = 0
    array_two_index = 0
    size_of_array_one = len(array_one)
    size_of_array_two = len(array_two)
    while array_one_index < size_of_array_one and array_two_index < size_of_array_two:
        if array_one[array_one_index] < array_two[array_two_index]:
            array_one_index += 1
        elif array_one[array_one_index] > array_two[array_two_index]:
            array_two_index += 1
        else:
            yield array_one[array_one_index]
            array_one_index += 1
            array_two_index += 1
```

**Advice 3**

Your `union` does not omit duplicates. You can deal with them in a following manner:

```
def union(array_one, array_two):
    array_one_index = 0
    array_two_index = 0
    size_of_array_one = len(array_one)
    size_of_array_two = len(array_two)
    while array_one_index < size_of_array_one and array_two_index < size_of_array_two:
        if array_one_index > 0 and array_one[array_one_index - 1] == array_one[array_one_index]:
            array_one_index += 1
            continue
        if array_two_index > 0 and array_two[array_two_index - 1] == array_two[array_two_index]:
            array_two_index += 1
            continue
        if array_one[array_one_index] < array_two[array_two_index]:
            yield array_one[array_one_index]
            array_one_index += 1
        elif array_one[array_one_index] > array_two[array_two_index]:
            yield array_two[array_two_index]
            array_two_index += 1
        else:
            yield array_one[array_one_index]
            array_one_index += 1
            array_two_index += 1

    while array_two_index < size_of_array_two:
        if array_two_index > 0 and array_two[array_two_index - 1] == array_two[array_two_index]:
            array_two_index += 1
            continue
        yield array_two[array_two_index]
        array_two_index += 1

    while array_one_index < size_of_array_one:
        if array_one_index > 0 and array_one[array_one_index - 1] == array_one[array_one_index]:
            array_one_index += 1
            continue
        yield array_one[array_one_index]
        array_one_index += 1
```

**Advice 4**

Note also that you don't need

```
if arrayOneIndex == sizeOfArrayOne:
```

in `union`; only one of the "leftover" loop will iterate at least once.

Hope that helps.